# What are the consequences (if any) of not running asyncio.set_event_loop(event_loop) after event_loop = asyncio.new_event_loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

What are the consequences (if any) of not running `asyncio.set_event_loop(event_loop)` after `event_loop = asyncio.new_event_loop`? And if there are none then what's the purpose of `asyncio.set_event_loop`?

I have written some basic test code without `set_event_loop` to figure out what it does and I saw no change, so now I'm left wondering what the consequences of not using it are / what the purpose of it is.

The documentation says: "Set loop as the current event loop for the current OS thread."

But I'm not sure how that's useful.

Test code:

```
import asyncio

async def test1():
    count = 0
    while True:
        count += 1
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print(count)

loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(test1())
```

### What I've learned since

asyncio.get_running_loop is thread specific and you won't be able to use it without setting the event loop to the current thread. In other words you cant run it without running asyncio.set_event_loop first

Comment: If you don't run asyncio.set_event_loop(event_loop) after creating a new event loop with `loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()`, the default event loop for the current thread will not be changed. This means that **the default event loop will remain the one that was set before**, or the one that was created when the asyncio module was imported, if no event loop was previously set.

Comment: @D.L what are the consequences of that, or how could that effect things?

Comment: and could you also provide me an example of when you wouldn't want that.

Comment: Regarding your latest edit: You should post that as an answer, instead of  including it in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your comment. Here is an example of when you might use `asyncio.set_event_loop(event_loop)`:

```py
import asyncio

# Create a new event loop
event_loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()

# Set the event loop as the default event loop for the current thread
asyncio.set_event_loop(event_loop)

# Run an asynchronous task using the event loop
async def my_task():
    print('Hello, world!')

event_loop.run_until_complete(my_task())

# Close the event loop
event_loop.close()
```

In this example, we create a new event loop using `asyncio.new_event_loop()`, and then set it as the default event loop for the current thread using `asyncio.set_event_loop(event_loop)`. We can then run an asynchronous task using the event loop with `event_loop.run_until_complete(my_task())`.

The code in the original question is already the counter example. In fact i tend to use the code in the question more than that code in this answer (because it was the historical conventional method).

You might use `asyncio.set_event_loop(event_loop)` if you want to create a custom event loop with specific settings or behaviors, or if you want to use a different event loop than the default event loop provided by the asyncio module....